# wpf cascaded combobox in Datagrid with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am looking for binding few cascaded combobox in a WPF GridView:

Following is my requirement:

I want to develop a grid view of persons records, which would hold their Name, state name and then City name. And of-course, City combobox data would depend on the State selected.

The data grid item source would be an ObservableCollection, the Person class would look like this:

```
class Person
{
    name string;
    state string;
    city string;
}
```

And View Model for the Datagrid Window would look like this:

```
class DatagridWindowViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<Person> PersonsList {get; set;}
}
```

And I don't want to keep the State and City lists in this class. And on changing State I should get Cities combobox populated properly from the enum.

I have enums for State and City.

1 enum for States which would have state names (say n states).
Then I have n no. of Cities enums

What could be the best way of doing it so that I can avoid keeping lists in the Person class following MVVM (i. e. I don't want to have any code behind).

I am new to SO, please let me know if my question is not clear or I am not able to ask the question in a correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Keep an Id for city and state in your VM, bind combos to a name-value pairs list that would be generated from the enums and then set the their selected values to the city Id / state Id of the Person.

Comment: Where would the list for Cities and States stay and how would that bind to xaml, thats what I am looking for

Comment: You may keep them as static resources. Populate the lists only once, e.g. on the first call and then cache them for later use. For getting name/value pair list from the enums, check the System.Enum API (GetNames and GetValues methods)